# Regex 3 number parts separated with dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a RegExp validation in JavaScript for string which can have 3 parts:

```
P1-P2-P3
```

With following rules:

- P1, P2 and P3 can only be digits
- each part can be 1-13 digits long
- entire string can not be longer then 20 characters
- P2 and P3 parts are optional (meaning `34` is already a valid string, or `34-6565` or, `566-233455-23232`).

Currently I have this, but I am missing the entire string length and I don't know how to define optional parts:

```
/^.\d{1,13}-\d{1,13}-\d{1,13}$/
```

Here are few valid entries: 5656, 33434-2323-45, 12-4345-12, 1234567890123-123456, 1234567890123-12-56

Invalid entries: 34453454351234566787, 1234567890123-1234567890123, 23455-233-123-3434, 34sd1322-23, 31234as, ...

Comment: Based on your question, this string in your example `34453454351234566787` isn't valid.

Comment: It is valid. It is 20 digits long?

Comment: @PrimozRome you better do this by javascript string manipulations. that will be understandeable and good in performance too.

Comment: @ojovirtual you were right, it is not valid because P1 is longer then 13 chars... Sorry my mistake I have modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?=\d{1,13}(-\d{1,13}){0,2}$)[\d-]{1,20}$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/sM6wQ7

#### Explanation:

[image]

Comment: @PrimozRome You can't check for string length in regex, not easily, at least

Comment: @PrimozRome: Actually I made an update and now it won't accept anything more than 13 in length.

Comment: Now explain it without looking at regex101.
A plain Javascript would be much more readable.

Comment: @Kroltan: Lookaheads are pretty powerful and this regex is easily understandable by breaking out into what is inside lookaheads and what is being matched outside `[\d-]{1,20}`.

Comment: @procrastinator: I have provided a link as well with same description.

Comment: The explanation is a joke, you might as well remove it.

Comment: @procrastinator: Yes please feel free to attach a screenshot by editing it.

Comment: @procrastinator: I just noticed you edited, many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 /(^\d{1,13}(-\d{1,13})?(-\d{1,13})?$){1,20}/
```

`?` means 0 or 1 of this, so this is useful for optional parts.

`{1,20}` at the end of the whole string to check it wont be longer than 20.

Comment: why `.` at first? just curious.. that is also showing valid to a number like `d345`.

Comment: @Mr_Green It was in the question :)

Comment: You're right, @Mr_Green, it was in the OP, removed.

Comment: -1. Because this matches `'1234567890-1234567890-1234567890'` (too long).

Comment: It matches strings longer then 20 characters

Comment: @PrimozRome It's nearly impossible to check for length and also match with a single expression.

Comment: @Kroltan Haha, bad loser ;P

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?!.{21,})\d{1,13}(-\d{1,13}){0,2}$/
```

`(?!.{21,})` at the beginning - negative lookahead meaning: not more than 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{1,13}-){0,2}(\d{1,13})
```

Matches two sets of numbers of up to 13 digits of length followed by a dash, then a set of numbers of up to 13 digits of length. This approach is extensible, because you just need to change the number after the first capturing group to change the amount of number parts you want. I would recommend you checking via code if the string's length is appropriate before validating trough Regex. It will be faster and more readable.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/wI7uX1

You could also do this via Javascript, and it may be quite faster: http://jsfiddle.net/sauYY/

Answer (score 0):

The total string length check must be separated; the rest can be done with regular expressions:

```
var re = /^\d{1,13}(?:\-\d{1,13}){0,2}$/;

if (str.length <= 20 && str.match(re)) {
    // valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
/^(?=.{0,20}$)\d{1,13}(-\d{1,13}){0,2}$/
```

Description :

```
^                  beginning of the input
(?=.{0,20}$)       followed by any char, 0 or 20 times, + end of the input
\d{1,13}           a digit, 1 or 13 times
(-\d{1,13}){0,2}   a dash + same as above, 0 or 2 times
$                  end of the input
```

More on regular expressions : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.